# is mailparse dll for windows php8.2 available?

Tags: php, dll, pecl, php-8.2

DLLs are available are for earlier versions of PHP, we are running 8.2
https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/ has windows PECL DLLs, but the most recent on this page for mailparse shows this error on PHP startup:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mailparse: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20210902
PHP    compiled with module API=20220829
These options need to match
```

PECL page: https://pecl.php.net/package/mailparse has DLLs up to v3.1.3 but current version is 3.1.6

Do I have to compile mailparse myself?
I have it running on linux (our production server), need to run it on Windows (development environment).

Comment: From `3.1.4` they haven't uploaded the pre-compiled `.dll` files yet. I am sorry to say that you have to build it from source for now.

Comment: Thanks, you could make this an answer & I'll accept it.

Comment: I won't be a valid answer according to StackOverflow's guide. Don't worry about it.